# How to replace many intermediate blank lines with only 1 blank line each

Tags: shell, sed, awk, newline

I am learning to use sed and have a hypothetical requirement:

```
bash$ cat states
California


Massachusetts


Arizona

Wisconsin
```

I would like the output: (Basically I want only one blank line in between)

```
California

Massachusetts

Arizona

Wisconsin
```

Please suggest ways to do it with sed.
Should it use concept of multiline pattern space etc.

Thanks,

Jagrati

---

In response to one of the comments, Ok, I ran some test scripts, and I was wrong with hypopthesis that address space selection criteria is applied only once. It seems to get activated again and again.

```
bash$ cat file 
a 
b 
c 
a 
b 
c 

bash$ sed -e '/a/,/b/s/$/x/g' file 
ax 
bx 
c 
ax 
bx 
c
```

I had the impression that it would yield:

```
ax 
bx 
c 
a 
b 
c
```

So could someone please explain how the sed proceeds in case of comma separated address spaces.

Comment: Sed processes the file in a loop. Regex addresses aren't absolute positions in a file. Each line is evaluated to see if it falls within a regex address range. Once the end of a range is reached, testing for the beginning of the regex range resumes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this it will delete all consecutive blank lines

```
cat states | sed '/./,/^$/!d'
```

outputs:

```
California

Massachusetts

Arizona

Wisconsin
```

Comment: It works, but can't quite understand how.. this uses comma separated addresses. 2nd address means a blank line. The first address means any single character. and then it deletes lines not matching this criteria. But isn't the address space selection applied only once. So how is it able to get rid of 2 blank lines between Massachusetts and Arizona.. Could you please explain how it's working..

Comment: Ok, I ran some test scripts, and I was wrong with hypopthesis that address space selection criteria is applied only once. It seems to get activated again and again.

bash$ cat file

a
b
c
a
b
c

bash$ sed -e '/a/,/b/s/$/x/g' file
ax
bx
c
ax
bx
c

I had the impression that it would yield:
ax
bx
c
a
b
c

Answer (score 2):

I know the OP explicitly asked for a solution using sed and/or awk, but the problem could also be solved with just cat:

```
cat -s file
```

Otherwise, here is yet another way to solve the problem with sed:

```
sed '/./!d; G' file
```

which exploits G to append an empty line to all non-empty lines found in files.

Comment: just a small note that this inserts blank line after the last line as well, but of course that can be taken care, by
sed -e '/./!d' -e '$!s/$/\
> /' states

So your basic idea of doing it in 2 passes basically works.

Answer (score 2):

This can be accomplished without `sed`, but also without meeting your requirement of learning `sed`:

```
cat -s states
```

It's interesting to note that the three examples for doing this given in [`info sed`](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#cat-_002ds) for GNU `sed` are each much more complex than [**dalton's**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270618/how-to-replace-many-intermediate-blank-lines-with-only-1-blank-line-each/3270678#3270678) and [**marco's**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270618/how-to-replace-many-intermediate-blank-lines-with-only-1-blank-line-each/3270918#3270918) answers.

Here are those versions condensed into one-liners:

```
sed ':x;/^\n*$/{N;bx};s/\n*/\n/' states

sed '1,/^./{/./!d};:x;/./!{N;s/^\n$//;tx}' states

sed -ne '/./!d;:x;p;n;/./bx;:z;n;/./!bz;i\ ' -e 'bx' states
```

Comment: Only the last of these 3 examples works. The 1st one inserts extra blank lines before the first line, and the 2nd one leaves no blank line between California and Massachusetts.

Comment: +1 for a correct answer that *only* uses `cat` -- I don't think I've ever seen that before :)

Comment: @learnerforever: I should have included the information from the `info` file which mentions leading and trailing blank lines. The missing blank line is a bug in their script! Changing the `1` to a `0` (GNU `sed` only) seems to fix that problem. The first one seems to be improved by adding `1!` right before the `s`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use awk as well

```
$ cat file
California


Massachusetts


Arizona

Wisconsin

$ awk 'NF{print;print ""}'  file
California

Massachusetts

Arizona

Wisconsin
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep . file > file_op
```

Comment: I don't think it replaces two empty lines with one.